# Read Text From TextBox in DataGrid MVVM (wpf databinding)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid of rows which contain data read from a web server and values I want to write into a webserver. I write the values in getting the user to input a number into the appropriate column and click an adjacent text box;

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagridDERControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF322D2D" Height="382" Margin="10,78,10,10" Width="972" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NFDataSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Write Set Point">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=WriteSetPoint, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Global Trip">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="buttonGlobalTrip" Width="100" Click="buttonGlobalTrip_Click"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid
```

How do I extract the specific textbox string per row to use in my view model.

Comment: What is VMMV? Do you mean MVVM?

Comment: Yes MVVM, sorry about that!

Comment: You should find an 'edit' button under your question. It might be an idea to correct your error and perhaps include some additional information *that is relevant to your question*.

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult to answer a question where the relevant details have been omitted by the question author. However, I shall try!

You have data bound (presumably) a collection property named `NFDataSource` to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. That is the collection that represents the data in your `DataGrid`, so to 'extract' a specific value, you need to look into your data items in your collection.

One handy property in the `DataGrid` class is the [`SelectedItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). this enables you to data bind an object (of the same type as those in your `NFDataSource` collection) to this property, which accesses the data object behind the row that is currently selected in the UI:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding NFDataSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Now you can utilise your `SelectedItem` property to access the values from the selected row in the `DataGrid`:

```
string someValue = SelectedItem.SomeProperty;
```

Comment: Sorry about the omission of details, would you have liked some of the view model source code as well? After I have bound the selected item to a property in my view model how do I access a specific cell? Is the cell the selected item (the textbox in this case)? Or is it the row, in which case I#d specify the column name? Thankd

Comment: No, the view model is irrelevant here... just think about it... what might have been useful to include? Perhaps it would have helped to know what type of object was in your collection for a start? The column (or cell) values come from the various properties of the item object. So, as I showed you in my example, to access some cell value, you could do something like this: `string someValue = SelectedItem.SomeProperty;`. Of course, if your collection is not of the type of a custom class, then maybe you don't have properties to access... I don't know... remember, you never told us.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this with MVVM and databinding, I'll assume you're using these and have just got muddled.

> "I have a datagrid of rows which contain data read from a web server
>   and values I want to write into a webserver."

So your viewmodel has a property, which is a collection of a custom class, that represents data fetched from a webservers.

> "I write the values in getting the user to input a number into the
>   appropriate column and click an adjacent text box"

So this VM property is two-way bound to a datagrid, so that each item in the collection represents 'one row', and the properties on those items represent your 'columns'. The user can make changes to the UI displayed values, and because of the two way databinding the VM property is also updated.

> "How do I extract the specific textbox string per row to use in my
>   view model."

Why do you need the specific textbox string, if it is databound to a property (or rather to a property on a class contained in a collection) in your VM anyway? If you've set up your VM this way, and are using databinding, you rarely need to worry about UI specific things such as which row in a datagrid is clicked.

As Sheridan points out though, you can also bind to properties on the datagrid such as `SelectedItem` so that you can perform additional operations beyond just reading/writing data. `SelectedItem` for your datagrid will be of the type that populates your VM collection, so will have the appropriate properties.

For example, if your VM collection is an `IQueryable<Person>` and that is bound to the `ItemsSource` of the datagrid then the `SelectedItem` will be of type `Person`. You could then have a VM property called `SelectedPerson` which is bound to that `SelectedItem`, and access things like `SelectedPerson.Name` etc.