# C# (wpf) datagridview data retrieve

Tags: c#, wpf

I am programming in c # wpf and I have a datagridview with more columns and I want to retrieve the data of a specific column so I first get index of the selected index and then try to get column value. my code is following

In debug I see that indexx I get correctly, but when I tried to get column value, it tells me that index is out of range.
I wanted to ask what am I doing wrong

```cs
int indexx = dtgrid.SelectedIndex;

string id = ((dtgrid.Columns[9].GetCellContent(dtgrid.Items[indexx]) as TextBlock)
  .Text
  .ToString());
```

Comment: how many columns do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to retrieve data from it from a DataGrids in that way. Instead use a view model to bind the data to TextBox which will then be changed by the when you write in the TextBox. Please note that the data will only update once your TextBox looses Focus, you could do Fancy using a Key_Up Event on all TextBoxes of the Grid and a timer to circumvent this limitation.

I strongly suggest you to have a look at this library: http://www.mvvmlight.net/

Here's a snippet from a similar question:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem}/>
```

Here you will get a reference to the selected cell as soon as it switches. Here's the link: [Read Text From TextBox in DataGrid MVVM (wpf databinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117030/read-text-from-textbox-in-datagrid-mvvm-wpf-databinding)

Answer (score 0):

Try 
Int indexx= datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex